# File download verification with selenium and java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, javascript, chromedriver, files

So I read all the other stackoverflow topics about this, none of the solutions worked for me so lets see if someone can help me.

I need to verify a download (csv) from an export button in chrome(driver) without a link but js. I can target the btn, click to start the download but then the chrome popup promp comes up which I cant target anymore. Not without switch to alert or other frame or window etc etc.

My chrome options are all correct and I've set accept_ssl_cert as well. I dont have any clue what to do. I am sure these options are correctly transfered since I can change the download directory and it changes in the prompt. In the automated chrome webdriver the box is also unchecked with 'ask where to save each file before downloading' however when I manually try to download something in here the prompt does indeed come up...

chromedriver preferences:

```
 download.prompt_for_download=false
 directory_upgrade=true 
 download.default_directory=/home/ 
 profile.default_content_settings.popups=0 
 plugins.always_open_csv_externally= true
```

anyone has an idea why this download popup always comes up? Or how to target it?
Or maybe a different way to verify the download is started/can be stared/is downloading?

Comment: can you screen shot of the popup and also link to any site where we can try the same behavior

Comment: sure.. any of these files at http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/download and screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/DATTLbR.png

Comment: Can you add your code also

Comment: my code is quite difficult because its super nested in a framework. but my driverprovider sets up my selenium chromedriver perfectly with the above preferences.

Comment: There are different ways to set preference just add that could which you use to pass preference to chrome driver

Comment: [drivermanager](https://pastebin.com/eR37tc8b), [chromedrivermanager](https://pastebin.com/eR37tc8b), [driverprovider](https://pastebin.com/Dd2DhjM9) [chrome.expiremental.properties](https://pastebin.com/Pc0g2cQa), [chrome properties](https://pastebin.com/zk4pJaQi)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Windows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", "D:\\temp");
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
driver.set(new ChromeDriver(options));
```

you should use `setexperimentalOptions`, and in Chrome87 ask for the prompt is turned off by default I guess.